# Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: dataView

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 6.2 and, when I use `<p:dataView ...>` my program crash.
This is the error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @15,65 <p:dataView> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: dataView
```

How can I solve it?

PS. I added the Jar file of PrimeFaces on classpath and, also, add the jar in webapp/WEB-INF/lib
PPS. Only for this tag I notice this error, others PrimeFaces tag work correctly.

Comment: AFAIR dataView is a new component, only available in the GitHub master or elite releases.

Comment: Yes it was added in PF 6.2.3 and higher:  https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3594  That explains why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is this was added in PF 6.2.3 and you are using PF 6.2.

Here is the GitHub ticket it was created for. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3594

Comment: Could not find artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.2.3 in PrimeFaces-maven-lib (http://repository.primefaces.org/) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Yes you have to be a PrimeFaces Elite subscriber to get Elite releases.  Only 6.2 is available in Maven Central.  https://www.primefaces.org/support/ Or you can choose to build from GitHub sources yourself.